# Same off-topic reason shown twice

Tags: support, custom-close-reasons

I vote to close [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695529/crossplatform-audio-metadata-library-for-c) today. Interestingly, the same off-topic reason is shown twice:

[image]

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Didn't find that question when searching. However, the status of that duplicate is **status-complete**, well, it's here again.

Comment: It really should be status-bydesign. Martijn's answer is the correct one to the question. Robert misread the question, but fixed another problem.